# Facing import builtins ImportError during installation of pgadmin4 in centos7?

Tags: python, centos7

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py", line 17, in  import builtins ImportError: No module named builtins

Comment: [root@localhost pgadmin4-web]# python /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    import builtins
ImportError: No module named builtins

Answer (score 1):

Execute it with python3.  IE:

python3 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py